# Horizontal Stack 2d Numpy Array with 3d Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, dataset, feature-extraction

I'm generating my feature dataset for machine learning, and I have a 2d numpy array X where X.shape = (n, d) - n samples, d features.

Now I generate a new feature with one-hot-encoding - f where f.shape = (n, 1, k) - n samples, k labels.

What would be the best way for me to add this new feature to my existing feature dataset?

Comment: What would be the final shape of the feature dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure what it should look like. I'm working with sklearn's libraries, what is the standard way of implementing a one-hot-label feature to my existing featureset?

Comment: I would just treat it like k new features `np.c_[X, f.reshape(n, k)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second dimension of the one-hot vector is redundant, so you can drop it and use f as a 2D array of shape `(n, k)`.
You would do something like:

```
new_data = np.concatenate((X, f.squeeze()), axis=1)
```

where the `squeeze()` function removes all 1-dimensions from you array (i.e. `f.squeeze().shape == (n, k)`.

Cheers